# php some forked processes keep running

Tags: php, debian, multiprocessing, fork

I have a php script that divides a task into multiple parts and runs each part in a separate child process. The code looks like this:

```
foreach($users as $k => $arr) {
  if(($pid = pcntl_fork()) === -1) continue;
  if($pid) {
      pcntl_wait($status,WNOHANG);
      continue;
  }
  ob_start();
  posix_setsid();
  dbConnect();
  // do stuff to data
  exit();
}
```

I'm running this script using crontab on a Debian server, but the problem is some processes keep running and reserve memory. After a while the server's memory is flooded.
I need to find a way to make sure all processes finish correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is the use of WNOHANG in the pcntl_wait call.  This means the pcntl_wait function exist before the child process - which you want, in order to be able to fork the other child processes concurrently.  But it has the side-effect that the main parent finishes before some of the children.  This link http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Managing-Standalone-Scripts-in-PHP/2/ describes how to loop using pcntl_wait with WNOHANG until all children complete.

Comment: thanks alot it worked now the parent process waits for all its children to finish running before it exits.

Answer (score 0):

The stuff you do to the data takes to long or forever. You need to debug the operations you execute.